# How to subscribe to an MVC checkbox change event in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to latch onto a checkbox change event using jQuery, currently I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({ datepicker: false, format: 'H:i' });
        $('.mondaystartfinish').hide();

        //subscribe to change events
        $('#IsMonday').change(function () {
            RunsOnMondays();
        });
    });

    function RunsOnMondays() {
        if ($('#IsMonday').prop('checked') == 'true') {
            $('.mondaystartfinish').slideDown();
        } else {
            $('.mondaystartfinish').slideUp();
        }
    }    
</script>
```

However in debug when I check/uncheck the box the `RunsOnMondays()` method is not firing.

I have tried using this also but still didn't work:

```
$('IsMonday').prop('checked').change(function () { RunsOnMondays();});
```

**Browser output**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="IsMonday">Monday</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsMonday field is required." id="IsMonday" name="IsMonday" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="IsMonday" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="IsMonday" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="startfinish">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="mondaystartfinish">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="MondayFrom">Monday Start</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="timepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field MondayFrom must be a date." id="MondayFrom" name="MondayFrom" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MondayFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="startfinish">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="mondaystartfinish">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="MondayTo">Monday Finish</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="timepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field MondayTo must be a date." id="MondayTo" name="MondayTo" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="MondayTo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: note: `prop('checked')` returns a boolean value! No need for `== 'true'`

Comment: Please show your page HTML (preferably browser output and not source as that makes a JSFiddle easier to produce) :)

Comment: is your html being rendered dynamically(ajax) ?

Comment: Just removing `== 'true'` *is* enough for your code to work, but I recommend using `slideToggle` with a boolean value to cleanup the code See *working examples* below.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Do you buy any chance have two elements with id of IsMonday?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that *this is not true* `true == 'true'` is actually `false`: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2wwz1ore/6/

`prop('checked')` returns a boolean value! No need for `== 'true'`.

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2wwz1ore/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('.timepicker').datetimepicker({ datepicker: false, format: 'H:i' });
    $('.mondaystartfinish').hide();

    // subscribe to change events
    $('#IsMonday').change(function () {
        RunsOnMondays();
    });
});

function RunsOnMondays() {
    if ($('#IsMonday').prop('checked')) {
        $('.mondaystartfinish').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.mondaystartfinish').slideUp();
    }
}
```

Better yet, use `slideToggle()`: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2wwz1ore/3/

```
    // subscribe to change events
    $('#IsMonday').change(function () {
        $('.mondaystartfinish').slideToggle($(this).prop('checked'));
    });
```

If (and I very much doubt it) your element is added dynamically, use a delegated event handler attached to a non-change ancestor element (`document` is the default if nothing else is closer/convenient)

e.g.

```
    $(document).on('click' , '#IsMonday', function () {
        $('.mondaystartfinish').slideToggle($(this).prop('checked'));
    });
```

Comment: But this can't be the fix for the event not firing

Comment: @Krishna: it is the fix... try the original code in the same JSFiddle and it will not work :)

Comment: As per OP, _the RunsOnMondays() method is not firing_

Comment: @Krishna: He *thinks* it is not running... It actually is: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2wwz1ore/5/

Comment: Possibly. What if he's dynamically generating the HTML? I agree that this fix is needed to make the functionality work, but in case OP is right, we might have to event delegation first and then the fix. Cheers.

Comment: It was a simple assumption that `true == 'true'` which is not true. Do not overcomplicate the problem in the absence of any other details :)

Comment: @SelectDistinct: just remember that `true != 'true'` :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Now that I had this discussion with you, I feel like I did overcomplicate it :)

Comment: @Krishna: I added a delegated event option, but I don't assume zebras when I hear hooves :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below as follows:

```
$('#IsMonday').change(function(){
    RunsOnMondays(this.checked);
});


function RunsOnMondays(isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        $('.mondaystartfinish').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.mondaystartfinish').slideUp();
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw8ou63/2/)**

Comment: Not that this is *wrong*, but why change to `click`? `$('#IsMonday').click(RunsOnMondays);` might be a bit shorter too if the anonymous function's only job is to pass on the checked parameter.

Comment: @RGraham Yes agreed, I had changed it before you answered.

Comment: I should pay more attention :)

Comment: @RGraham I should when answering. :)